# How to open a TabBarController in ViewControllers that Instantiate from SlideMenuViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to have tabBar in all my ViewControllers. I have implemented the SWRevealViewController, which have two view controllers linked one is TabBarController and another is TableViewController I wants to have the same tabBar in all my ViewControllers that Segues from TableViewController.

[image]

Comment: You need to implement a BaseClass viewController with UITabBar and then inherit all other controllers from BaseClass. Programatically no nib or storyboarding for this class

Comment: I am trying to use it as a delegate in the TableViewController, and the call back in MainTabBarController then I show the passed ViewController to the MainTabBarComtroller.

Comment: so it is working fine as you defined. Do you want controllers for tabbar or just side menu controllers used.?

Comment: I can help you with this (i have used  SWReveal in a couple of projects) but you gotta provide more context. For starters please update the storyboard image so i can see more of the connections and describe what's the app behavior right now.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to have tabBar in all my ViewControllers. I have implemented
>   the SWRevealViewController, which have two view controllers linked one
>   is TabBarController and another is TableViewController I wants to have
>   the same tabBar in all my ViewControllers that Segues from
>   TableViewController.

You can do some tweak like this, create the `custom delegate` and set `delegate` of `TableViewController` and `TabBarController` to `SWRevealViewController`. Now first time lets say you open the `TableViewController` and when tap on any cell then just invoke the `delegate` method which should execute inside `SWRevealViewController` class and then perform `segue` inside that class which should open the `TabBarController` and when click `back button` of `TabBarController` again invoke the `delegate` method which should execute inside `SWRevealViewController` class and perform `segue` to open the `TableViewController`

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be too difficult. Your `RevealViewController` (the initial controller of your storyboard) already seems to be a subclass of `SWRevealViewController`. This is good, but it's not essentially needed for this scenario. What you do need is a `UIViewController` implementation for your side menu. The Storyboard alone won't do.

Also, I wouldn't use segues here to switch between the tabs because a segue has a destination view controller. So every time you perform a segue, you would create a new instance of the destination view controller. I would rather implement a `UIViewController` that handles the cell selection of the `UITableView`

Now let's say you create a `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController` as your menu (actually the `RearViewController`). Make sure to assign this class to your `UITableViewController` in your storyboard.

```
class MenuViewController: UITableViewController {
    // MARK: UITableViewDelegate
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let tabIndex = indexPath.row
        let tabbarVC = (revealViewController().frontViewController as! UITabBarController)

        tabbarVC.selectedIndex = tabIndex // this assumes the menu items are in the same order as the tabs. if not you need to adjust this

        revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true) // close the side menu after switching tabs
    }
}
```

this should be all you need